# Get rid of the documentation tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [documentation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation) tag currently has the following description:

> Topics pertaining to sources for documentation and tutorials for
>   understanding Drupal core and extension modules, using its UI (user
>   interface), and the available code API (application programming
>   interface) features.

I guess this is the direct opposite of

> Questions asking to recommend or find a book, tool, module, theme,
>   distribution, tutorial, or other off-site resource are off-topic for
>   Drupal Answers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

Most of the posts using this tag are indeed request for resources, however there are some asking how to properly document some aspects of their code.

We should at least stop encouraging people from asking these kinds of questions, so should the tag be removed, or should it be modified to explain it is supposed to be about "How to document foo in case of" type of questions? Should all the currently tagged resource requests be closed?

Comment: May I get the reason of why this is a bad idea?

Comment: Yes, that tag description is encouraging to use it for off-topic questions, and indeed it is confusing for new users.

Comment: I appreciate the down votes, but can you leave some constructive feedback. In this case I believe this is big contradiction for users and confusing. So I am curious (not mad or disappointed ;) ) why some of you disagree. And if you have maybe other ideas to remove this confusion.

Comment: I edited the tag excerpt, and made clear that questions asking for tutorials are off-topic for us.